# How to visualize Elasticsearch excuted queries history

Tags: debugging, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-api

Hello Elasticsearchers,

I am new with Elasticsearch, I search a proposition to allow me debug the excuted queries because I am working with an elasticsearch PHP API so I want to visualize the body of excuted queries by Elasticsearch.

I tried that plug-in https://github.com/sonian/elasticsearch-jetty , but it seems old and I am working with elasticseach version 6.7.1, so I didn't get it to work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just 3 easy steps:

1. Configure the Slow Query Log (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html) with a treshold of 0 in order to have all queries logged.
2. Ingest the mentioned logfile into Elastisearch using Filebeat, Logstash or something else suits you.
3. Analyse / Monitor the queries using Kibana, Grafana or something else...

Have Fun!